# Pyramid "select" form input raise a KeyError

Tags: python, pyramid, html-select, mako

I am trying to access a `request.param` in my Pyramid application.

I saw a topic about checkboxes, but nobody talked about the "select" HTML tag.

On the pyramid view side, here is the part of my code which gathers the parameters:

```
if 'form.submitted' in request.params: # user
    user = User(request.params['nickname'],
                request.params['lastname'],
                request.params['firstname'],
                request.params['email'],
                request.params['password'],
                request.params['profile'])
```

On the Mako template side, my form is a simple HTML statement:

```
<select name="profile">
    % for profile in p:
        % if profile is u.profile:
            <option selected>${profile.name}</option>
        % else:
            <option>${profile.name}</option>
        % endif
    % endfor
</select>
```

Every time I try to reach the 'profile' parameter, I got a `KeyError...` exception.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

---

**UPDATE**: I can't get the `KeyError` Mako was throwing this morning... Maybe my co-worker fixed this, I need to check the last commits. Now the user is created the good way, but when I redirect the application user to the same form (with a validation message), I can't display the good  in the  statement. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Is there a full traceback for the error? If so, could you copy-paste that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to tell for sure without seeing what exactly is returned from the view, but if a key error is being thrown in mako, it usually means you are not returning that parameter from the view.  For example:

```
@view_config(route_name='myform', renderer='myform.mako')
def myform(request):
   if request.POST:
       # do stuff with submitted form ...       
   user ={'name': 'bob'}
   return {'user': user}
```

within myform.mako you can access user.name, but a key error is thrown if you try to access user.profile.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest.
 I'm returning the complete "user" object, but the error seems to happens in the other way, from the HTML form to an 'user' object generated by Pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but the profile parameter could be unicode and not str. But if it is only happening with "profile" and not others I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, actually this is happening for profile and another paramater taken from a <option> tag inside a <select> tag. Other parameters from classic <input> are ok... Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was corrected in a previous commit from one of my co-workers, and I can't get the KeyError now... Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should always edit a post, not post an answer. If you do post an answer, you should give the proper explanation (of how you resolved the issue) and accept it to close the question. Or accept any other answer.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I'll accept my own answer tomorrow (i can't now).

Comment: what I was trying to say is. If you post an answer please post with an explaination, so that it is useful to other readers. Or if you were able to get it fixed, you could have added a comment / edit. I would still like to know what was the fix that your co-worker made. I always get many such erros with cherry-py requests and thus i am always interested in knowing what could fail where :).